# How to get a primitive string from a String object in Java?

Tags: java

With an Integer object I can do this:

```
Integer one = new Integer(3);
int oneval = one.intValue();
```

Is there something similar for the String object?

Comment: no, the only you can do si to get char[]

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Integer` is the wrapper for an `int`, there is no _primitive_ `String`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html — note there is no "string primitive," though it mentions `String` as similar.

Comment: All Strings are reference types.  They are always objects.  The Java Language goes to great lengths to provide syntactic sugar so that, at times, they can -seem- like primitives ... but they are always reference types.  There is no such thing as a string primitive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no primitive `string` type in Java.  The closest you can get is to call [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) to get the `char[]` array of characters in the string (and it's a copy of the characters).

> Returns:
>
> a newly allocated character array whose length is the length
>   of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the
>   character sequence represented by this string.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that you also don't need one (a primitive `string` type), since `String` is immutable. (Of course, so is `Integer`...)

Answer (score 3):

Strings are not primitives in Java. Every String is an object.

What you can get from a String is a character array, or an encoded byte array. Although these aren't primitives, they're at least arrays *of* primitives.

```
  String s = "Twas brillig";
  char[] sChars = s.toCharArray();
  byte[] sBytes = s.getBytes();  // Default charset
  byte[] sBytes = s.getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") );  // Specific charset
```